# Matlab eig is not outputting a known output vector

Tags: matlab

I need to find the eigenvector of the matrix below. I know the output should be for lamda=1, we should see an output of (12, 4, 9, 6) but the V output makes no sense to me.

```
A=[0 0 1 1/2 ; 
    1/3 0 0 0 ; 
    1/3 1/2 0 1/2 ;
    1/3 1/2 0 0 ];

[V,D] = eig(A)
```

Output:

```
    V =
             628/871    +    0i           543/719    +    0i           543/719    +    0i           820/1619   +    0i      
             771/3208   +    0i          -215/708    -  163/471i      -215/708    +  163/471i     -1178/1945   +    0i      
             471/871    +    0i          -200/2147   +   64/233i      -200/2147   -   64/233i     -1641/4301   +    0i      
             314/871    +    0i          -472/1317   +  150/2101i     -472/1317   -  150/2101i      461/959    +    0i      


        D =

               1        +    0i             0        +    0i             0        +    0i             0        +    0i      
               0        +    0i         -1643/4556   +  337/820i         0        +    0i             0        +    0i      
               0        +    0i             0        +    0i         -1643/4556   -  337/820i         0        +    0i      
               0        +    0i             0        +    0i             0        +    0i          -635/2278   +    0i
```

In wolfram, and another source,
v_1 = (12, 4, 9, 6)

How do I obtain (12,4,9,6) as an eigen vector in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors are not unique, meaning that they could be at any magnitude as long as they have the same direction. Matlab normalizes eigenvectors if I recall correctly, so you can achieve similar results if you multiply the vector matlab provided with the magnitude of v_1 to make them have the same magnitude.

Comment: How can i scale it so V(:,1) its all integers and not the fraction you see above? Without knowing it to make it generic.

Comment: @Jim There is no way I know to convert a vector of type float to integers since the floating point removes some of the factors ( for example 1/3 becomes 0.333). but the normalized form is the most used form and making it in integers does not have any real applications.

Answer (score 1):

The first column of `V` corresponds to `(12,4,9,6)` in wolfram. The magnitude is different but the direction is the same.

If you scale `V` as:

```
V*871/628*12
```

You will get:

```
ans =
   1.2000e+01 + 0.0000e+00i   1.2569e+01 + 0.0000e+00i   1.2569e+01 + 0.0000e+00i   8.4296e+00 + 0.0000e+00i
   4.0000e+00 + 0.0000e+00i  -5.0541e+00 - 5.7598e+00i  -5.0541e+00 + 5.7598e+00i  -1.0080e+01 + 0.0000e+00i
   9.0000e+00 + 0.0000e+00i  -1.5504e+00 + 4.5716e+00i  -1.5504e+00 - 4.5716e+00i  -6.3501e+00 + 0.0000e+00i
   6.0000e+00 + 0.0000e+00i  -5.9648e+00 + 1.1882e+00i  -5.9648e+00 - 1.1882e+00i   8.0006e+00 + 0.0000e+00i
```

Notice that the first column is (12,4,9,6)

Comment: Without knowing I'm expecting 12, 4, 9 ,6 how can i obtain whole numbers?

Comment: Why do you want whole numbers? As long as you know the direction, you have the information need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain the rational eigenvector `[2, 2/3, 3/2, 1]`, which is equal to `[12, 4, 9, 6]/6`, by using the Symbolic Math Toolbox:

```
[v,d]=eig(sym(A));
simplify(v)
```

The result is

```
ans =
[   2, 2^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)/2 - 1, (2^(1/3)*3^(1/2)*1i)/2 - (2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*1i)/4 - 2^(1/3)/2 - 2^(2/3)/4 - 1, - (2^(1/3)*3^(1/2)*1i)/2 + (2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*1i)/4 - 2^(1/3)/2 - 2^(2/3)/4 - 1]
[ 2/3,                -2^(1/3),                                             -(2^(1/3)*(- 1 + 3^(1/2)*1i))/2,                                                  (2^(1/3)*(1 + 3^(1/2)*1i))/2]
[ 3/2,              -2^(2/3)/2,                                                (2^(2/3)*(1 + 3^(1/2)*1i))/4,                                               -(2^(2/3)*(- 1 + 3^(1/2)*1i))/4]
[   1,                       1,                                                                           1,                                                                             1]
```

(The vector `[2, 2/3, 3/2, 1]` is in the first column of the result)